# Outlook 2007 Rule or Search Folder to move/see all messages from anyone who's a member of a specified distribution list?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, email-filter, rules, distribution-list

Not messages from the distribution list itself, but from anyone who's a member of the list?  Specifically a server side list, not one I maintain in my own contacts.

I'm currently starting an email to the distro, expanding it, copy and pasting all those people into a "from specific users" condition.  But this is a huge pain and is obviously not dynamic as the distro changes.

There don't seem to be any rule conditions or search folder options that obviously do this.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This question is poorly formatted and lacks details. Please take a few minutes to add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: i have the same question

Answer (score 0):

Your current method of expanding the dynamic distribution list is the best way. There is no way to search the individuals that currently belong to a distribution list without individually searching on each individual.